# "addChildViewController:" crashes on iPad but not iPhone

Tags: ios, ipad, crash

I have an iPhone app that works great when running on the phone however crashes at launch when running on compatibility mode on the iPad. I use iAd in my project, specifically i'm using

> Bannerviewcontroller.h and .m

from the iAd suite to present the banner programmatically.

in my App Delegate I wrap some view controllers as follows.

```
 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2, *catVC3, *otherVC4;
UINavigationController *navController, *dognav, *catnav, *othernav;
    viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    catVC3 = [[catViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"catViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    otherVC4 = [[otherViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"otherViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];

    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
    dognav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
    catnav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:catVC3];
    othernav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:otherVC4];


_tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
 NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController,dognav,catnav,othernav,nil];
_tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;

//wrap tabbar controller in adbanner controller
_bannerViewController = [[BannerViewController alloc] initWithContentViewController:_tabBarController];
self.window.rootViewController = _bannerViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Then the crash happens here in my

> Bannerviewcontroller.m

```
    #import "BannerViewController.h"


@implementation BannerViewController
{
    ADBannerView *_bannerView;
    UIViewController *_contentController;
}

- (id)initWithContentViewController:(UIViewController *)contentController
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        _bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
        _bannerView.delegate = self;
        _contentController = contentController;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadView
{
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [contentView addSubview:_bannerView];
    [self addChildViewController:_contentController];
    [contentView addSubview:_contentController.view];
    [_contentController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    self.view = contentView;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return [_contentController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
        _bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    } else {
        _bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
    }
    CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds;
    CGRect bannerFrame = _bannerView.frame;
    if (_bannerView.bannerLoaded) {
        contentFrame.size.height -= _bannerView.frame.size.height;
        contentFrame.origin.y = _bannerView.frame.size.height;
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height - contentFrame.size.height;
    } else {
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
    }
    _contentController.view.frame = contentFrame;
    _bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 animations:^{
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 animations:^{
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}


@end
```

and throws this exception:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Whats going on here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells, that `_contentController` is not initialized. Where / how do you assign it? I can't see it in the AppDelegate code.

Comment: I edited my original post to include the entire bannerviewcontroller.m. This is directly from the iAd suite from Apple. Thanks.

Comment: You call the `init` method of `BannerViewController` with a `UITabBarController` as argument - in the examples, they call it with the individual views of the tab bar controller. See the example implementation in TabbedBanner/TabbedBanner/AppDelegate.m

Comment: I decided to take a different route. Since this is an iPhone app, iAd won't work when running in compatibility mode anyway. A simple if statement checks if the device is iPad. If it is then I skip the bannerviewcontroller all together and just assign the tabs to rootviewcontroller. If its an iPhone then I use the bannerviewcontroller as listed above.

Comment: O.k. - anyway, your initial question has been answered, right?